# Understanding Bash piping when used with cat command

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner at Bash, and I'm really struggling with piping. I find it to be a confusing concept. I wanted to print the content of files starting with 'a'.
using the find command with piping seemed like a good idea. Yet, it didn't work as expected.

I wrote: `find -name a* | cat`
expected the output: *a.txt* to be passed as the input of cat: *cat a.txt*
but what was printed at the end was '*a.txt*'
I anticipated this would work similarly to the command `ls * | grep "file1"`

Comment: `cat` does not behave like `grep`.  If you want to execute `cat` on each of the files listed by `find`, you could do `find . -name 'a*' | xargs cat` or `find . -name 'a*' -exec cat {} \;`

Comment: But to be accurate, you cannot really use `xargs` without `-0`, and you ought to write `find . -name 'a*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat`  Life is better if use reasonable filenames, but you cannot expect files to have reasonable names.

Comment: *"I anticipated this would work similarly to the command `ls * | grep file1`"*. Well, it does! `ls` prints file *names* and `grep` filters that list to print only lines (here file *names*, not contents!) containing `file1`. Neither command reads the content of those file here. Likewise, `find | cat` only processes file *names*, not contents. `find` lists the names, and `cat` prints them (the names, not their contents!) again.

Comment: Especially as a beginner, make sure to read the man pages of the tools you are using. _man cat_ will tell you that without any parameters, `cat` simply the stdin to stdout. Furthermore, `a*`  is expanded before `find` can see it. If you had done a `cat <(find . -name 'a*')`, you would get the content of all files starting with `a` which are in or below your  working directory. If you don't want this effect, I wonder why you use `find`, and don't simply do a `cat a*`.

Comment: First, thanks to all of you. 
Second, so `find` returns a list of paths of files matching the pattern, and then `cat` treats that list as if it's a content of a file and prints it? My understanding now is that
 `find -name 'a*' | cat` is equivalent to:
 `find -name 'a*' > temp`
 `cat temp`

Lastly, it seems my mistake is neglecting man pages, thank you @user1934428 for your advice

Comment: @Ghassen: Partially correct. Please here too, read the man page. Basically, `find` locates directory entries in and below the directories you specify in the command line (with GNU find, the working directory if none is specified=, and you *can* specify a pattern (if you do it correctly!), and by default it writes the file names matching the pattern to stdout. As usual, you can feed the stdout into another program where it receives this information via its stdin and can do whatever it wants to.

Comment: Alternatively, you can tell `find`to actually do something with the files. For example, `find foo -type f -iname 'bar*'  -exec cat {} ';'` finds all plain files in the tree below ./foo which start with _bar_ (case insensitive, i.e. _bAr_  would also be found), and prints the *content* of the files to stdout. Note the use of quotes in the command; correct quoting is crucial here.